# Key released in Python?

Tags: python, keyboard, keyboard-events

I am currently writing a stopwatch in python. In this, I want the starting to be triggered after the enter key is released. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do the trigger event by simply releasing the enter key

What you could do it something like this (In python 2.7 version)

```
import time
click1 = raw_input("Click Enter to start")
start = time.time()
click2 = raw_input("Click Enter to stop")
print time.time() - start
```

Hope it helped!